# Java Panels in Layer.. Mouse Events not Flowing through

Tags: java, mouselistener

I am working on connect 4 program and I am having trouble with mouse events. Here is the architecture of UI .

```
public class PlayConnect implements  MouseListener {

mainFrame = new JFrame("Connect-4");
basePanel = new JPanel();
mainFrame.add(basePanel);
gridPanel = new JPanel();
gridPanel.addMouseListener(this);
gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 7));
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                Cell tempCell = new Cell(i,j);
                gridUI[i][j] = tempCell;
                gridPanel.add(tempCell);


            }
}
```

Now Cell defined as

```
public class Cell extends JPanel implements  MouseListener{
}
```

The method MouseClicked of Cell is getting called when the cell is clicked on but not for class PlayConnect. I am not sure why. I did try changing type of gridPanel to JLayeredPane and it did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding your gridPanel as a MouseListener to your Cells

```
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            Cell tempCell = new Cell(i,j);
            gridUI[i][j] = tempCell;
            gridPanel.add(tempCell);
            tempCell.addMouseListener(this);
        }
```

Comment: Wow You are was quick ! As soon as minimized the Chrome window I saw the issue !

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. Added actionlistner inside the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                Cell tempCell = new Cell(i,j);
                tempCell.addMouseListner(this); // New listener
                gridUI[i][j] = tempCell;
                gridPanel.add(tempCell);


            }
```